# How to layout list items in groups

Tags: html, css

Let's say we have a html list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    ...
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

How to, using css and/or java script, make a browser show it like this (in groups of four, with some margin between the groups):

```
1 2    5 6    9 10
3 4    7 8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use css3 `column-count` property for this:

Write like this:

```
.colWrap {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -o-column-count: 3;
    -ms-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-width:20px;
    -moz-column-width:20px;
}
li {
    display:inline;
}
div{
    width:120px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/rJTGJ/2/

Comment: this demo does not work in IE9... also [WhenCanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-count) says IE 10 supports it...

Comment: Currently this seems to be the best solution. It looks exactly like i wanted, also in newer versions of Opera. The only problem is IE, and Opera 10. Suggested js for IE is not an option since it changes the html structure.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `column-count`, `float` and `width` after wrapping the `ul` in a parent element to which the `column-count` rule can be applied:

```
.colWrap {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -o-column-count: 3;
    -ms-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
li {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}​
```

Adjusted HTML:

```
<div class="colWrap">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rJTGJ/1/).

References:

- [`column-count` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/column-count).
- [CSS3 columns compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t410).

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by replacing the "ul" with tables, that fits your needs.
**[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/neysor/MafYp/)**

You only have to customize this demo for you needs with css or different html tags.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
    $("ul").each(function(){
        var oh = "<table><tr>";
        for(i=0;i<this.children.length;i++){
            oh += "<td>"+this.children[i].innerHTML+"</td>";
            if(i%2==1){
                oh+="</tr>";
                if(i%4==3){
                    oh+="</table><table><tr>";
                } else {
                    oh+="<tr>";
                }
            }
        }
        oh += "</tr></table>";
        this.outerHTML = oh;
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

There is also the possibility of CSS [column-count](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html), but this does not work in every browser. See [WhenCanIuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-count). So mine is a fall-back version which should work in much more browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way using jQuery here .. ([live demo](http://jsbin.com/awagek/7/edit))

```
var ul = $('ul'),
    lis = $('ul li');

lis.each(function (index) {
  if(index % 4 === 0) {
    ul.append($('<ul />'));
  }
  ul.find('ul').eq(~~(index / 4)).append($(this));
});
```

And CSS

```
ul ul {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use html tables

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And change the border characteristics of the table to hide it.
hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't tabular data so the OP should not use tables.